# URLRequest & Loader EventListener not firing for image

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, event-handling, addeventlistener

I'm loading images via a URLRequest and Loader classes and I want to manage the image when the request is complete. The example below doesn't fire the event when it is complete. The same code would work find for a URLLoader, but not a Loader object. Basically the image loads and the event listener is never fired. Can anyone tell me how to get an event to fire when Loader finishes loading an image.

```
var imageReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.google.com/images/nav_logo29.png");
var imageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
//
imageLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageComplete);
imageLoader.load(imageReq);

addChild(imageLoader);

function imageComplete(e:Event):void {
    trace("Image Complete");
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Typical. Few seconds after posting I find a solution, thought I should respond in case anyone else comes across the same problem.

Because you are loading another object you need to attached your event listener to that. You can use the contentLoaderInfo property to do that, like below.

```
imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageComplete);
```